# why we cannot use class method outside another class method?

Tags: c#, oop

This is my question:

```
class A
{
    B mB = new B();  //this is fine
    int y = mB.method1(); //this is error;

    public void method2()
    {
        int x = mB.method1(); //this is fine
    }
}
```

Can someone explain the differences above?

Comment: When would you expect it to execute?

Comment: Make your question more clear..

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194531/initializing-private-members-c-sharp)

Comment: What is the signature for `method1()`?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo and I just edited it.

Comment: good question, i never thought about it.

Comment: This article might help you understand what's going on here. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialization of [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) (at the same time as declaration) using methods in the class must be done on an *instance* of the class.

Since you do not allowed to refer to the instance itself (see section 10.5.5.2 in the C# language reference version 4.0 and [the comment by Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282335/why-we-cannot-use-class-method-outside-another-class-method/14282376#comment19837401_14282376)) when the field is initialized (as field initialization occurs before any constructors execute), this is not possible.

If the method called is static (therefore declared on the type), then you *can* call it, as static members get initialized before instance members..

---

Now, the order of field initialization is not guaranteed - this means that the compiler *may* decide to initialize `y` before `mB`. In which case, if calling a method on a field to initialize another field were allowed, you would get a `NullReferenceException`. It is better to avoid the issue in the first place and not allow this behavior.

Comment: Not true. Field initializers don't have to use constants.

Comment: @Eve In this context compile time *constant* means the compiler must be able to resolve the value of the field at compilation time.

Comment: @MattDavey Still not true. See: http://eve.cx/paste/811i0IBV.txt With Oded's edits now the answer is correct.

Comment: So instances are not created before the constructor? Whats the reason?

Comment: Because I've already create a reference to an object at the initialization of field of the Class A wasn't it?

Comment: Also note that the ordering of the initialization of fields isn't defined.

Comment: @user1701840 - Instances are created through the constructors - that's what constructors do.

Comment: But when I said New Class B(); in the initialization fields, is the constructor of Class B being constructed yet? If not, then how do I know when does it construct? Class A and B has no relationship.

Comment: @user1701840 - `new class B();` calls the parameterless constructor of `B`, which returns an instance of `B`.

Comment: Yes, right, then what is the reason of not able to call method from the reference of Class B? Because the construction of class B is already done isn't it? (Class A not constructed yet)

Comment: @user1701840 - Did you see the [comment by Servy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282335/why-we-cannot-use-class-method-outside-another-class-method/14282376#comment19831904_14282376)? The compiler may decide to initialize `y` before `mB`, at which case `mB` will be `null` and you get an exception. Instead of allowing for that possibility, calling a method on a field to initialize a field is not allowed.

Comment: @Oded, OH! I got you. So that's the main reason right? What about the the upvoted answer? "Since you do not have an instance when the field is initialized", do I have the Class B instance when I am in the initialization field?

Comment: @Oded, So during the construction of Class A, I will definitely have the Class B already constructed since I called new Class B() in my initialization field of Class A. Right?

Comment: This answer is close but not quite right. Of course there is an instance when the field initializers run; the fields being initialized have to come from somewhere. A better way to characterize the restriction is that `this` may not be used in any way in an instance field initializer.